# How do you use Docker build secrets with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using the `docker build` command line I can pass in a build secret as follows

```
docker build \
  --secret=id=gradle.properties,src=$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties \
  --build-arg project=template-ms \
  .
```

Then use it in a Dockerfile

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.0-experimental

FROM gradle:jdk12 AS build
COPY *.gradle .
RUN --mount=type=secret,target=/home/gradle/gradle.properties,id=gradle.properties gradle dependencies
COPY src/ src/
RUN --mount=type=secret,target=/home/gradle/gradle.properties,id=gradle.properties gradle build
RUN ls -lR build
FROM alpine AS unpacker
ARG project
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/build/libs/${project}.jar /tmp
RUN mkdir -p /opt/ms && unzip -q /tmp/${project}.jar -d /opt/ms && \
  mv /opt/ms/BOOT-INF/lib /opt/lib
FROM openjdk:12
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /opt/ms
USER nobody
CMD ["java", "-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:8000", "-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=5", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=600s CMD curl --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
COPY --from=unpacker /opt/lib /opt/ms/BOOT-INF/lib
COPY --from=unpacker /opt/ms/ /opt/ms/
```

I want to do a build using docker-compose, but I can't find in the [docker-compose.yml reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) how to pass the `secret`.

That way the developer just needs to type in `docker-compose up`

Comment: `docker-compose` does not support `buildkit` yet.  It should arrive in `1.25.0` docker-compose release. See https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/6865 https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6358

Comment: Did you ever found out how to do it since 2019? I think docker-compose has been updated but I still can't find how to pass ENV vars through it.

Comment: this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72188173/3666966

Answer (score -2):

You can use environment or args to pass variables to container in docker-compose.

`args:
    - secret=id=gradle.properties,src=$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`

`environment:
    - secret=id=gradle.properties,src=$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Comment: It won't work since `docker-compose`  not yet supports `buildkit`. I get `ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 4: Unknown flag: mount`. See https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/6865 and here https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6440