# docker-compose Equivalent to Docker Build --secret Argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

We have used the technique [detailed here](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-build-secrets/) to expose host environment variables to Docker build in a secured fashion.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
FROM golang:1.18 AS builder

# move secrets out of the build process (and docker history)
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=github_token,dst=/app/secret_github_token,required=true,uid=10001 \
    export GITHUB_TOKEN=$(cat /app/secret_github_token) && \
    <nice command that uses $GITHUB_TOKEN>
```

And this command to build the image:

```sh
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
docker build --secret id=github_token,env=GITHUB_TOKEN -t cool-image-bro .
```

The above works perfectly.

Now we also have a docker-compose file running in CI that needs to be modified. However, even if I confirmed that the ENV vars are present in that job, I do not know how to assign the environment variable to the `github_token` named secret ID.

In other words, what is the equivalent docker-compose command (up --build, or build) that can accept a mapping of an environment variable with a secret ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was a bit ahead of the times. docker compose v.2.5.0 brings [support for secrets](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/v2.5.0).

After having modified the Dockerfile as explained above, we must then update the docker-compose to defined `secrets`.

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
services:
  my-cool-app:
    build:
      context: .
      secrets:
        - github_user
        - github_token
...
secrets:
  github_user:
    file: secrets_github_user
  github_token:
    file: secrets_github_token
```

But where are those files `secrets_github_user` and `secrets_github_token` coming from? In your CI you also need to export the environment variable and save it to the default secrets file location. In our project we are [using Tasks](https://taskfile.dev/#/) so we added these too lines.

*Note that we are running this task from our CI, so you could do it differently without Tasks for example.*

```
- printenv GITHUB_USER > /root/project/secrets_github_user
- printenv GITHUB_TOKEN > /root/project/secrets_github_token
```

We then update the CircleCI config and add two environment variable to our job:

*.config.yml*

```yaml
  name-of-our-job:
    environment:
      DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
      COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD: 1
```

You might also need a more recent Docker version, I think they introduced it in a late 19 release or early 20.  I have used this and it works:

```yaml
    steps:
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 20.10.11
```

Now when running your docker-compose based commands, the secrets should be successfully mounted through docker-compose and available to correctly build or run your Dockerfile instructions!